# How to reuse content with Sencha Touch

Tags: mobile, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I want to build a mobile site in Sencha which showing HTML content on a tablet device, containing many objects/divisions/containers with similar layouts and properties.

Take this example window:

[image]

**Is there a best practice or recommended way to achieve reusability and DRY for writing those containers in Sencha Touch 2?**

What types of objects would you use? Does it make sense to use HTML `div` objects + CSS?

**Also, does it make sense to use Sencha in this case?**

Comment: Looking through sample apps, I found ample places where plain html and css were injected into objects...sometimes niftily with xtemplates. So yes, it makes sense but you have to weigh the pros and cons. Btw, what do you use to put together your wireframes? I like the results :-)

Comment: I am hardly trying to avoid use "nifty things", that's why I am asking this question :)

Comment: For the wireframes I use Balsamiq Mockups

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you would achieve that layout using Sencha Touch:

[image: layout]

Unfortunately it is pretty hard to explain, but hopefully it makes sense.

I've also created a very simple example of this layout, viewable here: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#jxiA8 (make sure you press **Run**).

As for which objects/components; they would all be [Ext.Containers](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Container). Ideally you would use the [MVC](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/first_app) structure to create custom classes (which would extend Ext.Container) for each of these items.

This is *definitely* a great use case for Sencha Touch. It is great for creating rich applications like this.

Comment: You put a lot of effort into your answer. This is what SO is about.

Comment: If you check the bio, rdougan is working for Sencha. As such the answer is weak. It is only about how to reproduce the overal layout, not about how to write components for reuse. The orange and yellow containers have the same structure for 'highlited content' and 'list content'. The content will be different. Probably obtained from a webservice.

Comment: I don't get paid to answer questions here, FWIW. But thanks for the bashing.

Comment: It's good to see Sencha staff take the time to check what users problems are and provide support outside of the official forums. Enthusiastic backing unsupported by clear evidence less so. I am referring to "This is definitely a great use case for Sencha Touch. It is great for creating rich applications like this.", with definitely in italic without any actual information on how Sencha helps you do DRY coding. Ideal would be to substantiate that claim. If you don't, best, would be to clarify that your are biased. That you are not paid doesn't remove the bias.

Comment: @rdougan, why do you use viewports instead of Ext.Panel or Ext.Container?

Comment: @KennyM. only the outer-most container is Ext.Viewport. Everything else would be a Ext.Container or Ext.Component, depending if it needs children. Ext.Viewport is automatically created when you run `Ext.setup` or `Ext.application`, so it makes sense to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach to render the list of items in the Orange and Yellow containers is probably with a DataView.

Relying on itemTpl to draw each item as per the official documentation of the [Ext.dataview.DataView component](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView) or using an item renderer, as per the [dive into dataview](http://www.sencha.com/blog/dive-into-dataview-with-sencha-touch-2-beta-2/) article. (Note that the code in that article may not work as sencha as changed a lot between the different beta versions - [@rdougan's associated demo on github](https://github.com/senchalabs/component-dataview-example/blob/master/app/view/KittensListItem.js) may be more recent).

I did expand on the layout code contributed by @rdougan to add an example of how to implement the [Reusable dataviews](https://gist.github.com/1915768) (gist).

That demo code also contains a quickly baked solution for data injection (applyStore and injectStore), so to make it possible to define an "OrangeContainer" once and only once and pass down different data for the "highlighted" and "list" versions of the views at the top and bottom of the screen, respectively. I have no idea whether this is a good or reliable way to do it. I would be interested in feedback on this.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the reusable dataviews.

Comment: Just skimmed through the code, and I get the intention. This is going to work great. Maybe I should reconsider the best answer.